# Does spin class prepare you for a long bike ride?

Tags: training

I need to train for an upcoming bike ride and i wanted to see if attending a spin class 1-2 times a week (45 min course) would be appropriate way to prepare for a long bike ride (50 - 75 miles)

Comment: Probably a bit better than your typical "spin class" cycles are some sort of cycle that varies the effort required.  A number of different exercise bikes have time-varying "profiles", and bikes like the [Expresso](http://ifholdings.com/products_services/upright_bike.html) can provide a very realistic ride.  But, as others have indicated, while these are good adjuncts to training (and a good way to keep in shape through the winter, eg), they don't provide the full bike "experience", and don't train you to handle the dynamics of the bike.

Comment: BTW, if you're only a few weeks from this ride you're probably overthinking it.  Try to get in a good 60-90 minute ride every 2-3 days.  On the bike is best, but if weather or other conditions prevent that then the exercise bike (in or out of "class") is a decent alternative for maybe half your rides.  On ride day just pace yourself, take a break every hour or two, and mind your hydration and nutrition.  Don't try to set any speed records.  Can the anxiety -- relax and enjoy the ride.

Comment: You'll get more benefit by a few miles riding to and from the spin class as well. Especially if you push during the class. Riding home when you're tired will help you build those riding skills the gym can't teach you.

Comment: Its now 2017 and tools like Zwift and interconnected devices have appeared.  You can "ride"  a virtual segment, and have your bike's power meter translate your effort into a representation of forward movement.  Downside, you need a lot of stuff like a power meter with rollers or trainer with a built-in power meter, and a laptop/computer with TV, and an internet link.  And a cooling fan.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Regular aerobic exercise is definitely of value for preparing for a big ride. Spin is a good preparation in conjunction with some outdoor rides, but it is not a substitute for riding your bike on the road.

The feel of the bike, the balance, the momentum, and the environmental and traffic factors will have an effect on your fitness as well, some of which may be purely mental.

If time is limited, try spin 2-3 days a week, and build up your endurance, but also do at least one longer outdoor ride each week. If you're riding 50 miles, you need to plan to be on the bike for 3-5 hours when you do the actual ride.

Build up to where you can handle 3 hours on the bike easily, and you'll do fine.

Comment: +1 in particular, riding on a stationary spinning bike does not by itself promote good, efficient form which is useful for long rides. The only way to do that indoors is with rollers (but you can't use those for a spinning class!). Spin class is still one of the best ways to develop aerobic capacity, however.

Comment: Also spin training doesn't help train with gear selection.

Comment: The crank inertial load is also not the same as riding in the real world, which can make real world riding feel more difficult. Most trainers cannot duplicate this as it would require a variable mass flywheel (or one that could change the inertial load).

Comment: @Rider_X That's true, but do keep in my that those trainers are available. Expensive, but available. :)

Answer (score 20):

Yes and no.

Spin classes do help with overall aerobic fitness.

There are shortcomings: the first thought occurring to me is "bike handling". You can do spin classes blindfolded. An actual ride means controlling the bike in various situations. Secondly in a spin class, the "rider" determines the difficulty. Actually riding, the difficulty is determined by the environment.

The upshot is that spin classes are good for aerobic fitness but other skills require different practice.

*Spin workouts in general?* 
A good thing. I do spin workouts during the dark, wet, and cold Pacific NW winters. Spin workouts do wonders for your cardiovascular endurance. So, you have that covered.

However, spin workouts generally last 45 minutes to an hour. A long ride is typically longer than that, so little to no help. Another thing in spin workouts is that the instructor will have you increase the resistance for "hills"; believe me, it never matches reality unless you ***really*** ramp up the resistance. Another thing, is that spin instructors often don't have actual experience in riding a real bike on real terrain; so not sure that it helps unless the spin instructor is actually a cyclist.

Take away? Usually ramp things up; of course depending on the spin instructor.

...Spin "class" is NOT a "class"...it's a workout...

Answer (score 6):

In my experience the saddles on gym spin bikes are often a little more plush than a typical "real" bike saddle. Thus, one part of your body that you will never train, no matter how many spin classes you attend, is your butt's ability to tolerate a bike saddle for 50-75 miles.

I believe the only way to train your butt to sit without significant discomfort on a real bike saddle for 50-75 miles is to sit on a real bike saddle for a significant number of miles. Several times.

I took a coworker on an easy, flat 25-mile route, and he was not accustomed to being on a bike saddle for that long. By the time we got back, he was effectively riding on one cheek, because the saddle was paining him so. His speed had slowed to a crawl.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have much experience on the bike, in a long event, be ready for pain in your hands, wrists, shoulders, back, and bottom.  Especially if your bike fit isn't perfect.

I ride 50-100mi per week (mostly road, some mountain), and my first spin class was really hard for me.  I think the reverse is true as well; a good spinner may find that actual road riding is more dynamic and challenging.

Try to get as many road rides in as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Spinning is fine if it's a long session but no substitute because your 100Km race is an endurance test for your muscles. So as others have said hydration is more important than your time.

Do the spinning but make sure you've ridden the 100KM on the real bike at least once before you do your trip. Just so you'll know what's coming.

Hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone training for a big bike ride I would recommend the following. Go out once a week and do a long ride increasing the  distance by ten per cent a week. Do a shorter ride during the week, and if you can fit some interval training in on a spin bike that really helps with stamina. A pyramid climb with some interval sessions straight after. After one of your training sessions preferably the longer ride I did some squats, lunges and single leg deadlifts. This really helped my climbing ability. All the hills I dreaded became mere blips, not just physically but visually. I did the ride London and a 
ride in France which was shorter than the London one but hilly.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Lol. Thanks for answering one of our questions. Can you edit to explain what a *pyramid climb* is, please? In general we recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're answering see [answer] also.

Answer (score 0):

its appropriate. i do spinning every winter. great training, really pushes me. you'll do fine as long as its not a competitive event and you can ride your own pace. 50-70 miles is not that long if you're on a racing bike. as others said: dont expect it to be too comfortable tho. cycling is an endurance sport, after all. I'd say do some riding too. it's almost summer in the northern half of the world. perfect time for some relaxed riding. if you dont like that, then why even bother going to the event? if you do like it, then youll probably enjoy it more than sweating in some overheated gym class. its also good (pleasant and safe) to be familiar with your bike and riding, cornering etc when you ride in big groups.

Answer (score -1):

I SPIN 8-12 hours a week in winter- )Pacific Northwet). I make sure I do one or two 2 hour sessions a week. It has been very effective for years. One key is to have imperial information: 
watts and heart rate to make sure you are getting benefit. Some call for watts = your weight is good target. I add the weight of my bike to that as well. I also did a test for threshold watts that provides me with targets during training. I do not have it on my bike just trainer and spin bike.

Comment: Your weight in what units? Pounds or kilograms? Also, sorry to be picky, but I think you mean "empirical" not "imperial".